# How to post message to friends wall in Twitter using ID

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to send invite message to user friend using twitter ID, But can not get the idea how to do that can someone point me right direction code or tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The [STTwitter API](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) I find is a great resource for implementing twitter in to your app. The "README" file contains a lot of informative code snippets and descriptions as does this developer video: [STTwitter Developer Video.](http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2014/6/17/xcode-5-tutorial-ios-7-app-only-authentication-twitter-api-version-11) Youtube and google are great resources for this type of thing, you can find a lot of help and tutorials.